# Intersection point of perpendicular lines to two other point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems

I got this question which confused me and I can't find the solution,

The two lines have equations

Line $1$ :  $r = (3,5,4)+t(2,3,1)$

Line $2 $:  $r = (1,1,-1)+s(1,1,1)$

Where s and t are constants.
These lines don't intersect.
A line perpendicular to line $1$ and line $2$ intersect line $1$ and line $2$ at points $P$ and $Q$ respectively.
Find the coordinates of $P$ and $Q$.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that $(2,-1,-1)$ is perpendicular to both $(2,3,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$. As such, the line perpendicular to both lines can be written as
$$\vec r=(x_0,y_0,z_0)+a(2,-1,-1).$$

Here $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(3+2t,5+3t,4+t)$ are the coordinates of $P$ for some $t$. Since the perpendicular intersects the second line at $Q=(1+s,1+s,s-1)$, we have

$$(3+2t,5+3t,4+t)+a(2,-1,-1)=(1+s,1+s,s-1),$$
which results in $$3+2t+2a=1+s,$$ $$5+3t-a=1+s,$$ and $$4+t-a=s-1.$$
Solving them for $a$, $t$, and $s$ results in $a = 5/6$, $t=1/2$, and $s=14/3$.

Consequently, the coordinates of $P$ are $(3+2t,5+3t,4+t)=\color{red}{(4,13/2,9/2)}$ and that of $Q$ are $(s+1,s+1,s-1)=\color{red}{(17/3,17/3,10/3)}$.

Answer (score 0):

use that the dot product of direction vector of your searched equation must Zero, this means
$$[2;3;1]\times[x;y;z]=0$$
and
$$[1;1;1]\times [x;y;z]=0$$
at first compute $[x;y;z]$